# NextJS and i18n Trans Component do not translate dynamic props/content from GraphQL/Apollo

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, apollo, next.js, i18next

I’m having some hiccup with incorporating i18n trans component into NextJS and any help would be greatly appreciated.

We are using GraphQL and Apollo for query calls. We have a description container component that takes a description prop. The prop can sometimes be a json object and sometimes regular strings (with a function to parse the json if needed).

We set up internationalization with next-i18next and it works for everything that’s in our static English files.

Problem: dynamic content/props using Trans Component by i18n are not working.

We tried the following and none of them worked:
Regular T approach -

```
t('activityItemName', { activityName: activity.activityName })
```

Trans approach 1 -

```
        <Trans i18nKey="translatedDescription">
            <ThingDescription
                description={rawData.description}
            />
        </Trans>
```

Trans approach 2 -

```
         <Trans
            i18n={i18n}
            i18nKey="activityItemName"
            defaults="<0>{aName}</0>"
            components={[<span key="0">dummy</span>]}
            values={{ aName }}
          />
```

I’m new to i18n translation/internationalization so any help or suggestions/directions welcome! Thanks!